# Convergence of a multiple integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I'm wondering for which $p \in R$ the
multiple integral 
\begin{equation}
\iint\limits_{0 < r < \sin^{\frac{1}{5}}(b),{0<b<\frac{\pi} {2}}}
\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!r^{p+2} \sin^p(b)\cos(b)\,\mathrm dr\,\mathrm db 
\end{equation}

converges? Please, can somebody show me how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every $b$ in $(0,\pi/2)$, the integral
$$
\int_0^{(\sin b)^{1/5}}r^{p+2}\mathrm dr
$$
diverges at $r=0$ if $p\leqslant-3$. Since everything is nonnegative this implies that the double integral diverges. If $p\gt-3$, it is bounded uniformly (by $\frac1{p+3}$, for example) then the double integral converges if and only if
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2}(\sin b)^{(p+3)/5}(\sin b)^p\cos b\mathrm db
$$
converges. The only problem is at $b=0$ where $(\sin b)^{(p+3)/5}(\sin b)^p\cos b\sim b^{(p+3)/5+p}$ hence the integral converges if $(p+3)/5+p\gt-1$, in which case its value is
$$
\left.\frac{(\sin b)^{(p+3)/5+p+1}}{(p+3)/5+p+1}\right|_0^{\pi/2}=\frac{1}{(p+3)/5+p+1}.
$$
Finally, for every $p\gt-3$ such that $(p+3)/5+p\gt-1$, that is, for every $p\gt-4/3$, the double integral is
$$
\frac1{p+3}\cdot\frac{1}{(p+3)/5+p+1}.
$$
and for every $p\leqslant-4/3$, the double integral diverges.

Comment: @sbr, not iff p > -3 ?

Comment: Are you sure? the integral $\int_0^\alpha r^{p+2}\mathrm dr$ converges iff $p>-3$, (Problem at 0).

Comment: Indeed I assumed implicitely that $p$ was nonnegative (and I should not have). Answer modified to take into account every (real) value of $p$.

Comment: But integral of $sin^m (x)$ from 0 to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ also diverges for m<-1. We should take it into account.. And it turns out that p should be greater than -4/3?

Comment: Indeed. See revised version. Thanks.